# How to find the latest account in a chain of old and new accounts?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

I have a dataframe with three columns, old account, new account and date. For every account, I want to trace the path through each row of the dataframe to the find the latest account on record, and write it to a new column.

Simple example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'new_account': ['A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'B2'],
                'old_account': ['A0', 'B0', 'A1', 'B1'],
               'date': ['Jan 2019', 'Feb 2019', 'Mar 2019', 'Apr 2019']},
             index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

```
    new_account     old_account       date
0   A1              A0              Jan 2019
1   B1              B0              Feb 2019
2   A2              A1              Mar 2019
3   B2              B1              Apr 2019
```

This shows that account A0 went into A1, and then A1 went into A2, B0 went into B1, which eventually went into B2.

I want to end up with a situation looking like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'new_account': ['A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'B2'],
                'old_account': ['A0', 'B0', 'A1', 'B1'],
                'date': ['Jan 2019', 'Feb 2019', 'Mar 2019', 'Apr 2019'],
                'latest_account': ['A2', 'B2', 'A2', 'B2']},
             index=[0, 1, 2, 3])`
```

```
    new_account     old_account       date           latest_account
0   A1              A0              Jan 2019               A2
1   B1              B0              Feb 2019               B2
2   A2              A1              Mar 2019               A2
3   B2              B1              Apr 2019               B2
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a mapping table (pandas series) from old_account to new_account and use `Series.map` to conduct mapping. In the case of no map, use new_account data.

```
old_to_new_map = df1.set_index('old_account')['new_account']

df1['latest_account']=df1['new_account'].map(old_to_new_map).fillna(df1['new_account'])
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`. I think this means that more than one 'old_account' goes to a 'new_account'?

Comment: @Falc That means the relationship between your old_account and new_account is not unique. From one old_account you could map it to multiple new_account